# How to extract patterns from a string when one pattern occurs zero or more times

Tags: android, regex

I want to extract elements of a string that can take one of two forms.

```
Form A = "nnnnnnnnntext1=12abc&text2=67xyz&nnnnnnnn"

Form B = "nnnnnnnnntext1=12abc&text3=az345&text2=67xyz&nnnnnnnnnn"
```

Text1 and Text2 will always be there, Text3 may or may not be there.

I can do this using 2 separate patterns

```
Pattern A = Pattern.compile(text1=(.*?)&.*text2=(.*?)&);
Pattern B = Pattern.compile(text1=(.*?)&.*text3=(.*?)&.*text2=(.*?)&)
```

But is there a way that I can do it using a single Pattern?  Is it possible to construct a pattern will extract text1,text2 and text3 if it is there but not fail if it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it makes sense to replace `.*?` with `[^&]*` to make the pattern match the last value even if it is just at the end of the string and make matching a bit more efficient.

To solve the issue, you need to wrap the greedy dot with the capturing group with an optional greedy group:

```
text1=([^&]*)&(?:.*text3=([^&]*)&)?.*text2=([^&]*)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R2hAze/1/).

**Details**

- `text1=` - literal text
- `([^&]*)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than `&`
- `&` - a `&`
- `(?:.*text3=([^&]*)&)?` - an optional non-capturing group that is tried at least once and matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `text3=` - literal text
  - `([^&]*)` - Group 2: 0+ chars other than `&`
  - `&` - a `&`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `text2=` - literal text
- `([^&]*)` - Group 3: 0+ chars other than `&`

Comment: Thank you!!  This solution works well for both eventualities.  I like the [^&] solution as well - smart :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use non capturing group and make it optional

```
text1=(.*?)&(?:.*?text3=(.*?)&)?.*text2=(.*?)&
```

[image]

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/jq9x1k/4/)

Comment: Currently you are not capturing the optional text3 because I think the first `.*` should be non greedy `.*?`  https://regex101.com/r/sSHqvg/1 Note that you could save a lot of backtracking using a negated character class instead.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, pattern B missed the text3 element.  Aside from the [^&] negation both patterns are the same except that the working solution has the .* within the optional non-capturing group.  Still trying to figure out why that is making the difference.  Thank you, though, for your reply.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks mate for the feedback, and comments about backtracking is really useful :)

Comment: @DougConran this is not working due to greediness, since the non capturing group is optional so the `.*` will try to as much as possible, so we need to make it lazy, or use negated character as suggested by other answer